# C# Comparing values from 2 tables in SQL Server Database 2005 and displaying in Gridview in VS2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server Database 2005.

I am tying to compare values between 2 databases.

I am able to retrieve the variable [StudentName] from tStudent Table via a SELECT WHERE sql statement, as follow:
[image]
[image]

Now, I have another table named StudentDetails. It has 3 columns, StudentName,Address and ContactNum:
[image]

The situation is that I want to grep the result from the first SQL query on tStudent, which returns me a list of Students whose [Status]=DELETED.

And from the list of Students queried , I want to take one Student at a time, and search through my [StudentDetails] table.

If it exist in [StudentDetails], I wan to use a way to store the variable [StudentName] from StudentDetails table and display it in GridView on my webpage. 
(open to many solutions here. store in database; display result in GridView; store in array; etc)

May I know what the ways and steps I can take to achieve the result?

Step by step guide and code snippets are very much appreciated, because I am quite weak in C# programming.

Comment: what have your already tried so far for this?

Comment: i am looking for solutions such as joining two tables in a sql statement, haven't tried anything yet so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

- Use Visual Studio to create a DataSet name StudentDS, create table name "Student" in this DataSet, this table will contain 3 table columns: String StudentName; String Address; String ContactNum;
- Fill deleted students into this DataSet:

DataSet dset = new StudentDS();
String connectionString = "";// depends on your database system, refer to http://www.connectionstrings.com

```
        using (connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select StudentName, Address, ContactNum from tStudent WHERE status = 'DELETE'";

        OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = command;

        da.Fill(dset, "Student");
    }
```

- After you get this DataSet, you can iterate on its row to do what you want.

```
if(dset.Tables[0].Rows != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count, i++){
if(!ExistInStudentDetail(dset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["StudentName"]))
{
dset.Tables[0].Rows.remove(i);
i--;
}
}
}
```

//here, boolean ExistInStudentDetail(String StudentName) is a method, you can create sql for this as same in above.

- In your form, add a new DataGridView name "StudentForm",add 1 column for this DataGridView name "StudentName", and set its binding property to "StudentName" (same column name in DataSet), and then set DataSource of this grid.
  StudentForm.DataSource = dSet;

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple issues but the scope is pretty large.  So here goes:

First you should really make sure you have unique columns in the tables you are searching this allows you to modify those individual rows and make sure that you are modifying the correct one.  I didn't see any ID columns in the screenshot so I just wanted to cover this.

Second I would create a class for students.  In here I would create fields or properties of all the information that I wanted.

```
class Student
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public string Address { get; private set; }
  public string ContactNum { get; private set; }
}
```

you can either use a constructor in the above class and fill the properties with that or you can fill in each through your select your choice.

Third I would create a `List<Student> students;` this will be used as your reference list

```
List<Student> deletedStudents = SQL Select Statement;
```

Fourth I would then create another `List<Student> detailedStudents;`

Finally I would compare the two lists and then do something when a match is found.

Comment: Hi CBRRacer, I do not really know what the Student class do. I see that you have stored the deletedstudents in a list (deletedStudents). How can I take one result from the list at a time from (deletedStudents) to compare with the second List (detailedStudents)?